# What is the DATA step equivalent of this SQL query?

Tags: sas

Hi: Anyone who is good at SAS please turn this SQL into a DATA step:

```
create table tableD nologging as
select 
  a.acct,
  b.app_dt,
  case when a.acct in (select acct from tableC) then 1 else 0 end prom_ind
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.application_no = b.application_no
where to_char(b.app_dt,'yyyymmdd') between '20150101' and '20150630' ;
quit;
```

Comment: To get help please explain in words what the SQL is doing.  Also provide sample input datasets and what the result dataset should be for that sample inputs.

Comment: you can use the same thing in proc sql except last where statment .you can chage it to app_dt between '01Jan2015'D and '30Jun2015'D

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you know how to `MERGE` two data sets ? Do you know the data set option `in=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rough attempt, untested because no data or such.

First merge and join on application number and then add the flag in another step. Or you could modify the SQL to work in PROC SQL which is a trivial exercise.

```
data part1;
merge tableA (in=A) tableB(in=B where=(appt_dt between '01Jan2015'd and '30Jun2015'd );
by application_no;
if a and b;
keep acct app_dt application_no;
run;

data part2;
merge part1 (in=p1) tableC (in=C);
by acc;
if p1;
if p1 and C then prom_ind=1;
else prom_ind=0;
run;
```

SAS SQL:

```
proc sql;
create table tableD nologging as
select 
  a.acct,
  b.app_dt,
  case when a.acct in (select acct from tableC) then 1 else 0 end prom_ind
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.application_no = b.application_no
where b.app_dt between '01Jan2015'd and '30Jun2015'd ;
quit;
```